# Aligning 3 div's CSS

Tags: html, css

This is driving me crazy.

I'm trying to align 3 div's between 80% of the screen... but it's not happening.

I'm getting the header and nav div's at 100%, then my slider and footer div's at 80%, but the 3 div's in between (that I was to use as columns with height:auto; ... but I can't get it working.

Take a look at my code.

Also the annoying part is it looks ok in Dreamweaver, but the second I load it in the browser it looks awful.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Test Site</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Sydney CBD FC</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar"></div>
    </header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="homeslider"></div>

  <div class="homebox">
        <p>I've done a lot of searching and I've found outdated tutorials that don't work...

I have a site made with PHP and when I submit a particular form in my admin area, I want to publish to my Facebook "fan page"

There is no RSS available, so do you have any example to directly post to the Facebook fan page (not user wall) using php sdk?

Thank you!</p>
    </div>
  <div class="homebox2">
        <p>I've done a lot of searching and I've found outdated tutorials that don't work...

I have a site made with PHP and when I submit a particular form in my admin area, I want to publish to my Facebook "fan page"

There is no RSS available, so do you have any example to directly post to the Facebook fan page (not user wall) using php sdk?

Thank you!</p>
    </div>
  <div class="homebox3">
        <p>
            I've done a lot of searching and I've found outdated tutorials that don't work...

I have a site made with PHP and when I submit a particular form in my admin area, I want to publish to my Facebook "fan page"

There is no RSS available, so do you have any example to directly post to the Facebook fan page (not user wall) using php sdk?

Thank you!
        </p>
    </div>



<footer>

</footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */


* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
}

header {
        width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
}
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.header {

    background-color: #7B0A0B;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom:auto;

}

.navbar {
    background-color: #E4383B;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;

}

.homeslider {

    width: 80%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #7C7C7C;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.homebox {

    background-color: #898989;
    height: auto;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.homebox2 {

    background-color: #898989;
    height: auto;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.homebox3 {

    background-color: #898989;
    height: auto;
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 8px;

}

footer {

    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #898989;
    clear: both;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: not exactly sure what you are looking to accomplish. can you make a mock-up so we can see what you are trying to do?

Comment: 3 evenly aligned columns.

Comment: It looks fine to me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apOLeM

Comment: which browser are you having issues with?

Comment: do you want everything inside 80% of screen?

Comment: When I load on Safari the 3 boxes stretch 100% of the screen. The two to the left remain close together when I change the screen size, whereas the one to the right changes.

Comment: I want everything below the header 80%

Comment: padding :auto could be your problem

Comment: If you can't see load the link, I'm more or less trying to replicate the layout of http://www.hibernianfc.co.uk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132549/discussion-between-happymacarts-and-chris).

Comment: Your link should be removed that is to a local server and does no one else any good (attach an image if you want us to see it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code some css issue.

Implementing box-sizing [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```css
/* CSS Document */

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.header {
  background-color: #7B0A0B;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: auto;
}
.navbar {
  background-color: #E4383B;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.homeslider {
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #7C7C7C;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
footer {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #898989;
  clear: both;
  margin: auto;
}
.three-box {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  width: 80%;
}
.three-box * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.three-box .three-box-row {
  margin: 0 -15px;
}
.three-box .three-box-row:after {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
.three-box .homebox {
  width: 33.3333%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.three-box .box {
  background-color: #898989;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Test Site</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Sydney CBD FC</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar"></div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="homeslider"></div>

    <div class="three-box">
      <div class="three-box-row">
        <div class="homebox">
          <div class="box">
            <p>I've done a lot of searching and I've found outdated tutorials that don't work... I have a site made with PHP and when I submit a particular form in my admin area, I want to publish to my Facebook "fan page" There is no RSS available, so do
              you have any example to directly post to the Facebook fan page (not user wall) using php sdk? Thank you!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="homebox">
          <div class="box">
            <p>I've done a lot of searching and I've found outdated tutorials that don't work... I have a site made with PHP and when I submit a particular form in my admin area, I want to publish to my Facebook "fan page" There is no RSS available, so do
              you have any example to directly post to the Facebook fan page (not user wall) using php sdk? Thank you!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="homebox">
          <div class="box">
            <p>I've done a lot of searching and I've found outdated tutorials that don't work... I have a site made with PHP and when I submit a particular form in my admin area, I want to publish to my Facebook "fan page" There is no RSS available, so do
              you have any example to directly post to the Facebook fan page (not user wall) using php sdk? Thank you!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <footer>

    </footer>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I hope its helpful to you..

Comment: which lines did you change (i don't wanna read it all or diff it)?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. That's has solved the issue. I'll need to go over the code so I know what I'm doing for next time.

Comment: Thank you, If it's working for you then check as upvote so its batter for other one.